# Solr Search 8.4.1 Not Finding Results

Tags: solr, lucene, lucene.net, solrnet

I am having an issue getting Solr Search setup. I am new to Solr, but I believe the issue is with the solrconfig.xml file. But please tell me if I'm wrong!

The issue is that if I type a search in the `q` field on the Solr admin page, I get 0 results. However, if I type a wildcard query like `*"query"*` I'm returning all documents in the database. Here is the solrconfig.xml file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>8.4.1</luceneMatchVersion>

  <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>

  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory"
                    class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}"/>

  <codecFactory class="solr.SchemaCodecFactory"/>

  <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>

  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">

    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
      <int name="numVersionBuckets">${solr.ulog.numVersionBuckets:65536}</int>
    </updateLog>

    <autoCommit>
      <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime>
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
    </autoCommit>

    <autoSoftCommit>
      <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime>
    </autoSoftCommit>

  </updateHandler>

  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       Query section - these settings control query time things like caches
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <query>

    <maxBooleanClauses>${solr.max.booleanClauses:1024}</maxBooleanClauses>

    <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                 size="512"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="0"/>

    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                      size="512"
                      initialSize="512"
                      autowarmCount="0"/>

    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="512"
                   initialSize="512"
                   autowarmCount="0"/>

    <!-- custom cache currently used by block join -->
    <cache name="perSegFilter"
           class="solr.search.LRUCache"
           size="10"
           initialSize="0"
           autowarmCount="10"
           regenerator="solr.NoOpRegenerator" />

    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>

    <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>

    <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
    <listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
      </arr>
    </listener>
    <listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
      </arr>
    </listener>

    <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>

  </query>

  <requestDispatcher>
    <httpCaching never304="true" />
  </requestDispatcher>

  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- <lst name="defaults"> -->
      <!-- <str name="echoParams">explicit</str> -->
      <!-- <int name="rows">10</int> -->
    <!-- </lst> -->
  </requestHandler>  

  <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="indent">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/spell">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>

  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    <!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">_text_</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>  

  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <searchComponent name="terms" class="solr.TermsComponent"/>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the terms component -->
  <requestHandler name="/terms" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="terms">true</bool>
      <bool name="distrib">false</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>terms</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
      <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
      <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
      <fragmenter name="gap"
                  default="true"
                  class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- A regular-expression-based fragmenter
           (for sentence extraction)
        -->
      <fragmenter name="regex"
                  class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
          <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
          <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
          <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
          <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
          <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
      <formatter name="html"
                 default="true"
                 class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </formatter>

      <!-- Configure the standard encoder -->
      <encoder name="html"
               class="solr.highlight.HtmlEncoder" />

      <!-- Configure the standard fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="simple"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the single fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="single"
                       class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the weighted fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="weighted"
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.WeightedFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- default tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="default"
                        default="true"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <!--
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.multiValuedSeparatorChar">/</str>
        </lst>
        -->
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="colored"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
               <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
               <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
               <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
               <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
               <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
          <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <boundaryScanner name="default"
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>

      <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator"
                       class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- type should be one of CHARACTER, WORD(default), LINE and SENTENCE -->
          <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
          <!-- language and country are used when constructing Locale object.  -->
          <!-- And the Locale object will be used when getting instance of BreakIterator -->
          <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>
    </highlighting>
  </searchComponent>  

  <searchComponent name="query" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent" />
</config>
```

And here is the schema.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema name='test2' version='1.1'>
    <types>
        <fieldtype name='string' class='solr.StrField' />
        <fieldtype name='long' class='solr.TrieLongField' />
        <fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true" />
        <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"/> 
    </types>

    <fields>
        <field name='id' type='long' required='true' />
        <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
        <field name='title' type='text' />
        <field name='parentCategory' type='text' />
        <field name='childCategory' type='text' />
        <field name='body' type='text' />
        <field name='url' type='text' />

        <dynamicField name='*_string' type='text' multiValued='true' indexed='true' stored='true' />
        <copyField source='*' dest='_text_' />
        <field name='_text_' type='text' indexed='true' multiValued='true' stored='true' />
    </fields>

    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
    <df>_text_</df>
    <solrQueryParser q.op='OR' />
</schema>
```

Can anyone help me get the search working here?

Edit:
Using exact phrases does work. For example, if I have a title called "Test Title" and I use the search phrase `title:"Test Title"` it works as expected. But I should be able to use the search query of: `title:"test"` and have the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `schema.xml` there is no reason anything should be matched, except for exact hits. Your TextField does not have a tokenizer (which splits text into words / tokens) or any filters (which process the text further).

Instead you probably want to base your field on one of the `text_` types available [in the default config, such as `text_general`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/field-type-definitions-and-properties.html):

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This will split your text into separate tokens on a number of different characters (such as whitespace, `-`, etc.), then apply a StopFilter (removing `the` and other non-relevant words) and at last apply a LowerCaseFilter - meaning that everything will be lowercase when matching. Since lowercasing happens both when indexing and querying (given by the `index` and `query` types of the chain definition), this makes your search in practice case insensitive.

After making any changes like this (in particular, to anything that changes how content is indexed), you have to reindex your content (i.e. submit all documents to Solr again).

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, Solr provides you with some inbuilt token filters. For your case, i think EdgeNGramFilterFactory  and NGramFilterFactory will work, as you need partial tokens to be matched without passing a Regex expression. You can find more about this at this link  : https://hostedapachesolr.com/support/partial-word-match-solr-edgengramfilterfactory  . You can always configure this filter as per your needs  . If you are new to filters in Solr, this part of the documentation may help you  https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/understanding-analyzers-tokenizers-and-filters.html .

Comment: I tried adding this to my schema.xml file per the documentation you provided, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: However, it added `"SynonymQuery(Synonym(_text_:tes _text_:test))"` to the parsedquery field in debug. So the filter seems to have added correctly, but still have the same results.